# What is the difference betwwen != and not in XPath

Tags: xml, database, xpath

I have a question about the difference between `!=`  and `not()` in XPath.

For example this is my XML database:

```
 <Books>
   <Book title="one">
      book1
   </Book >
   <Book title="one">
      book2
   </Book >
   <Book >
      book3
   </Book >
 </Books>
```

what is the differences between those two XPath queries:

- `//book[@title!='one']`
- `//book[not(@title)]`

So if I am asking : How much book i get from the **first request** and how much book i will get from the **second request**.

In the example above with the 2 request ,do i will get the last book "book3" element as a result?

Thank you.

Comment: `//book[@title!=one]` should probably be `//book[@title!='one']`. If that's true, please edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `//book[@title!="one"]`

means *"select book node that doesn't contain `title` attribute that equals to `'one'`"*

- `//book[not(@title)]`

means *"book node that doesn't contain `title` attribute at all"*

First one can be written with `not()` as `//book[not(@title="one")]`.

Comment: thank you @Andersson .i will edit my question to give exact question.

Comment: could you please confirm if with //book[@title!='one'] , i will get the last book?

Comment: @zakzak , in this case node with `title` attribute should be found first and then the value should be evaluated. If node doesn't contain `@title` False should be return without evaluation

Comment: so i will not get the last book in my result if i understand well.

Comment: Yes. It should not be matched by `//book[@title!="one"]`

Comment: @zakzak , There is something that you should also know. Considering updated source code, `//Book[not(@title="one")]` WILL match the last Book node!

Comment: not easy question as we can think. i don't see why with //book[@title!="one"] we dont get the last book,and with //Book[not(@title="one")] we get it.could you explain a little bit why?

Comment: `not(@title="one")` should match all nodes, except those who have `@title="one"` while `@title!="one"` - those who have `@title`, but it's not equal to `"one"`

Comment: ok i misunderstood,you fliped != to = . thank you for your help